# BigQuery "Schrödingers Row" or why ROW_NUMBER() is not a good identifier

Tags: google-bigquery

### Situation

We have a fairly complex internal logic to allocate marketing spend to various channels and had currently started to rework some of our queries to simplify the setup. We recently came across a really puzzling case where using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` to identify unique rows lead to very strange results.

### Problem

In essence, using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` resulted in what I call Schrödingers Rows. As they appear to be matched and unmatched at the same time (please find replicable query below). In the attached screenshot (which is a result of the query) it can be clearly seen that

`german_spend + non_german_spend > total_spend`

Which should not be the case.

[image]

### Query

Please note that execution of the query will give you different results each time you run it as it relies on RAND() to generate dummy data. Also please be aware that the query is a very dumbed down version of what we are doing. For reasons beyond the scope of this post, we needed to uniquely identify the buckets.

```sql
###################
# CREATE Dummy Data
###################
DECLARE NUMBER_OF_DUMMY_RECORDS DEFAULT 1000000;

WITH data AS (
  SELECT
    num as campaign_id, 
    RAND() as rand_1,
    RAND() as rand_2
  FROM
    UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, NUMBER_OF_DUMMY_RECORDS)) AS num
),

spend_with_categories AS (
  SELECT
    campaign_id,
    CASE 
      WHEN rand_1 < 0.25 THEN 'DE'
      WHEN rand_1 < 0.5 THEN 'AT'
      WHEN rand_1 < 0.75 THEN 'CH'
      ELSE 'IT'
    END AS country,
    CASE 
      WHEN rand_2 < 0.25 THEN 'SMALL'
      WHEN rand_2 < 0.5 THEN 'MEDIUM'
      WHEN rand_2 < 0.75 THEN 'BIG'
      ELSE 'MEGA'
    END AS city_size,
    CAST(RAND() * 1000000 AS INT64) as marketing_spend
  FROM
  data
),
###################
# END Dummy Data
###################

spend_buckets AS (
  SELECT
    country,
    city_size,
    CONCAT("row_", ROW_NUMBER() OVER()) AS identifier,
    #MD5(CONCAT(country, city_size)) AS identifier, (this works)
    SUM(marketing_spend) AS marketing_spend
  FROM 
    spend_with_categories
  GROUP BY 1,2
),

german_spend AS (
  SELECT
    country,
    ARRAY_AGG(identifier) AS identifier,
    SUM(marketing_spend) AS marketing_spend
  FROM 
    spend_buckets
  WHERE
    country = 'DE'
  GROUP BY
    country
),

german_identifiers AS (
  SELECT id AS identifier FROM german_spend, UNNEST(identifier) as id
),

non_german_spend AS (
  SELECT SUM(marketing_spend) AS marketing_spend FROM spend_buckets WHERE identifier NOT IN (SELECT identifier FROM german_identifiers)
)

(SELECT "german_spend" AS category, SUM(marketing_spend) AS marketing_spend FROM german_spend
UNION ALL
SELECT "non_german_spend" AS category, SUM(marketing_spend) AS marketing_spend FROM non_german_spend
UNION ALL
SELECT "total_spend" AS category, SUM(marketing_spend) AS marketing_spend FROM spend_buckets)
```

### Solution

We were actually able to solve the problem by using a hash of the key instead of the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` identifier, but out of curiosity I would still love to understand what causes this.

### Additional Notes

- Using `GENERATE_UUID() AS identifier` instead of `CONCAT("row_", ROW_NUMBER() OVER()) AS identifier` leads to almost 0 matches. I.e. entire spend is classified as non-german.
- Writing spend_buckets to a table also solves the problem, which leads me to believe that maybe `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` is lazily executed or so?
- using a small number for the dummy data also produces non-matching results regardless of the method of generating a "unique" id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash functions are a way better for marking rows than generating a  rownumber, which is changing each day.

The CTE (`with` tables) are not persistent, but calculated for each time used in your query.

Running the same CTE several times within a query, results in different results:

```sql
With test as (Select rand() as x)

Select * from test
union all Select * from test
union all Select * from test
```

A good solution is the use of `temp table`. A workaround is to use search for CTE table, which creates a row_number or generates random number and are used more than once in following. These CTE are to rename and be used in a recursive CTE and then the later CTE is used. In your example it is the `spend_buckets`:

```sql
WITH recursive
...
spend_buckets_ as (
...),
spend_buckets as
(select * from spend_buckets_
union all select * from spend_buckets_
where false
),
```

Then the values will match.

Comment: Super interesting. Thanks for sharing your insights.